# Strange android plural behavior

Tags: android

I have following string:

```
<plurals name="title">
    <item quantity="one">This %d item would be added to your card</item>
    <item quantity="other">These %d items would be added to your card</item>
</plurals>
```

As per [Plurals Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals) some languages like korean, japanese, etc. would always return the "other" string because they don't have separate words for singular (item) and plural (items). But what about "This" and "These"? They do have different words for those, but it does not matter because Android will always ignore "one" in this type of languages, this does not seem right to me?

Comment: Did you find the solution?